# My google app engine website is only displaying my main page after migrating to python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to get the other pages to show?
I this is my main.py

```
import webapp2
import os
import jinja2

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
  loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                        ('/',MainPage),
                                        ], debug=True)
```

And this is my app.yaml

```
application: ftmyersptcong
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version:  latest

handlers:  
- url: /styles
  static_dir:  styles

- url: /images
  static_dir:  images

- url: /scripts
  static_dir:  scripts

- url: /.*
  script: main.application
```

I keep getting a 404 Not Found Page when I to click on any of the links to other pages which have been href'd in my html code.
 This is what is in the log:

```
INFO     2014-11-12 18:15:42,434 module.py:652] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2014-11-12 18:28:21,151 module.py:652] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1274
INFO     2014-11-12 18:28:21,272 module.py:652] default: "GET /styles/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1880
INFO     2014-11-12 18:28:27,512 module.py:652] default: "GET /downloads.html HTTP/1.1" 404 154
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you go to /downloads.html? You only have a route and handler defined for "/" in your MainPage WSGIApplication definition. You should define "/downloads.html" as another route and map it to whatever handler you want to deal with that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a handful of static directory routes defined in your app.yaml (images, scripts, styles) -- that's why your css file is loading fine, for example. Then you have everything not matching those directories going to "application" in your "main.py" file.

In there, you are currently only defining one route -- "/" and MainPage is defined as your handler for that route. Calls to "/downloads.html" get sent to that same router, but since it doesn't match the "/" route, a 404 is returned.

You need to define your other route(s) and handlers in your main.py. For example:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                        ('/',MainPage),
                                        ('/downloads.html',DownloadPage)
                                        ], debug=True)
```

Then you'd define DownloadPage similarly to MainPage to handle that route. You can also do pattern matches in the route definition in order to pass along variable info, but for your example, the above should work.

Comment: I am so happy! Thank you for helping me out here! New programmer over here. I ended up basically creating more handlers for my pages and lo and behold they worked. `application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
          ('/',MainPage),('/index.html',MainPage),('/downloads.html',DownloadPage),('/signin.html',SignIn)
         ], debug=True)`